# Photo upload prevent overwriting

Tags: php, html, upload

So I've followed this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to make a photo uploading capability but rather than it saying that the file has already been uploaded when there is another file of the same name, how would i just make it change the file name to something else that hasn't been used before.

in other words, if there is another photo of the same name I still want it to upload but I don't want it to overwrite the existing one.

I basicaly want to replace this with something else to do that

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
```

so that its something like this

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
"do something to change file name"
$uploadOk = 1;
```

UPDATE: I got it to work. I just made it so that it renames every image to a unique id like stated bellow. thanks

also in that suggestion it should be this

```
$newTarget_file = $target_dir . uniqid() . "." . end($target_file);
```

Comment: Just check `file_exists($target_file)` if so then rename and upload your file

Comment: but can I do that automaticaly? I don't want them to have to rename it just to find out that name was also taken and then have to do it again

Comment: Randomly generate the file-name on the sever after the upload?

Comment: yes that is mainly what i want, but I do not know how to do that and is why I am asking

Answer (score 1):

add random numers to rename file

```
$name = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newName = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($name);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newName );
```

Or you also put if condition to verify if file name is exist or not. And if file is available add something to rename your file.

Comment: Should use [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid) instead of a random between 1-9999 ^^

Comment: if you want to add uniq id then it should be use as
$newName =uniqid().end($name);
or
$newName =end($name).uniqid();

Comment: this still just overwrites it

Comment: So generate another one if it exists?

Comment: never mind I got it to work I spelled something wrong when I put the suggestion in.